# How is ReCaptcha Fool Proof?

Tags: recaptcha

I have a website and started getting a lot of spam, even though I use ReCaptcha. Upon investigation, I found out that ReCaptcha only needs one of the two words entered correctly for you to pass the test. [source](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore)

Unless I'm reading it wrong, it appears that ReCaptcha pairs a word it *could* read with one that it *couldn't* read, thus forming the challenge.

If Google's OCR program could read the word for which the answer is known, what stops just any bot from OCR'ing the ReCaptcha and getting the word that is needed and just using garbage for the one which isn't?

Comment: It isn't, as simple as that! read this: http://news.cnet.com/8301-31921_3-20127715-281/outsmarted-captcha-security-not-much-of-a-gotcha/ and it is from 2011 imagine now!

Comment: Interesting Article, but it says Google's is the only one that works: "The only tested Captchas that withstood the researchers' attacks were Google's." (8th paragraph)